# Correlation matrix with missing data

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

My data has the following structure and i would like to get a correlation matrix from it but there is some missing data. The code I use as follow does not return the correct output. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Input `c_ret` numpy array:

```
1   2    3    4    5   6 
              4    5   6
1   2    3    4    5   6
1   2    3    4    5   6
                   5   6
1   2    3    4    5   6
```

The wished output calculate the correlation even when there are missing numbers, though the correlation coefficient is calculated on a smaller set of data (depending on the data available). In this case, the correlation of the second row (which has only the last 3 data points) with the other rows would be calculated by cutting all the other rows at the number 4. Except for the 5th row which will need to be the same size as 2nd row.

My code:

```
 corr_mat = np.corrcoef(c_ret, rowvar=True)
```

The output:

```
1   1    1    1    1   1 

1   1    1    1    1   1 
1   1    1    1    1   1 

1   1    1    1    1   1
```

Wished output:

```
1   1    1    1    1   1 
1   1    1    1    1   1 
1   1    1    1    1   1 
1   1    1    1    1   1 
1   1    1    1    1   1 
1   1    1    1    1   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `np.ma.corrcoef` with `np.ma.masked_invalid`

```
c_ret = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,  4.,  5.,  6.],
                  [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
                  [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
                  [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,  5.,  6.],
                  [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]])


np.ma.corrcoef(np.ma.masked_invalid(c_ret), rowvar=True).data

Out[293]:
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```